# Using caddy to serve a tracking pixel (base64 encoded)

Tags: caddy, caddyfile

I am trying to setup a very simple beacon (pixel tracking) server. Currently all I want to do is have caddy respond with a 1px transparent gif to every request. The URLs will be logged and then we'll parse out the analytics data we're after.  However, I can't get Caddy to serve the gif! It appears as a broken image.

#### Caddyfile

```
:2015

header Content-Type "image/gif"
header Content-Encoding "base64"
respond /* 200 {
  body "R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"
  close
}
```

I believe that is the correct encoding for a base64 gif.  Tested it with

```html
<body>
  [<img src="http://localhost:2015/foo.gif" />]
 [<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7">]

</body>
```

If you load that up, you'll see the inline one is fine, but, the other is not.

I don't particularly want to have to serve an actual file (or use `file_server` or anything else), however, if that's the only way then I'll do it.

Any help would be wonderful!

-------------Edited to add---------

After the helpful comment I ended up with this simple caddyfile to serve a 1px image.   I placed the pix.gif inside `/home/patrick/caddplay/temp/pix.gif` and then rewrite all requests to that. Seems to work just fine.

```
:2015

header Content-Type "image/gif"
handle /* {
    root * /home/patrick/caddplay/temp
    rewrite * /pix.gif
    file_server
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No* browsers support `base64` as a `content-encoding` value for a response body, as opposed to `gzip`, `deflate` and `br` (Brotli), which are commonplace.

If you're aiming at the highest possible performance, perhaps this can help  you:

- Caddy should use `sendfile`, so the kernel can send your static pixel file efficiently. The file might actually be transparently cached in memory by your OS. Try and see if there's *actually* any overhead from responding with a file as opposed to a static string like you're doing now.
- I guess you could put the pixel on a tmpfs if you wanted to avoid any seeks on your disk, but I imagine with a SSD (and noted above, caching in memory by the OS) this won't lead to a measurable improvement.
- There are a lot of Caddy plugins, but I haven't seen one that can decode base64-encoded strings on the fly, but perhaps you could create one yourself?

* neither popular browsers nor any esoteric UA I know of.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply. I'll work on getting the sendfile working.